# Best way to get a value from service file to app.module

Tags: angular

I wish to import a value returned from a service file let's say for example the service file is:

**http.service.ts**

```js
selectedEnvironment() {
  return "abc";
}
```

But how can I get this value into my `app.module` file. Is there a preferred way?

I tried:

**app.module**

```js
import { HttpService } from "./http.service";

export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, "./assets/" + HttpService.selectedEnvironment()+"/i18n/", ".json");
}
```

But it says "Property `selectedEnvironment` does not exist on type `typeof HttpService`".

Comment: `selectedEnvironment` does not exist on `typeof HttpService` because it is an instance member. Try setting `selectedEnvironment` as a `static` method.

Comment: try new HttpService().selectedEnvironment() or make the method static like joh04667 commented

Comment: How do I make it static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an Angular Service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class YourHttpService {
  constructor() {}

  getEnvironment() {
    return "XYZ";
  }
}
```

You can specify the service as a parameter in **HttpLoaderFactory**. Please make sure that service name is specified in    **deps: [HttpClient,YourHttpService**] as well as in providers **providers: [YourHttpService],** of your app module

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient,httpService:YourHttpService) {
    console.log(httpService.getEnvironment());
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient,YourHttpService]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [YourHttpService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Sample Code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/transalate-vvmckq?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

in app.module.ts add this

```
 providers: [HttpService]
```